# json.net deserializing @prefixed properties

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize json i retrieve from a website into POCOs, and I am stuck on the fact, that json.net will not deserialize properties with a preceding `@` sign.

I have found numerous posts on SO, which state the solution to this is to annotate the C# properties in the POCO with the `JsonPropertyAttribute` and specifying the property name directly. I have done so, however, my C# property stays `null`.

POCO code:

```
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Event : IEvent
    {
        private readonly String name;
        private readonly String context;
        private readonly String type;
        private readonly UInt32 id;
        private readonly DateTime startDate;
        private readonly DateTime endDate;

        public Event(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "@context")]
        public String Context { get { return this.context; } }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always, PropertyName = "@type")]
        public String Type { get { return this.type; } }

        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public String Name { get { return this.name; } }

        public UInt32 ID { get { return this.id; } }

        public DateTime StartDate { get { return this.startDate; } }

        public DateTime EndDate { get { return this.endDate; } }
    }
```

Deserializing code:

```
public void Test()
{               
    string innerHtml = @"{
        ""@context"": ""http:\/\/ schema.org"",
        ""@type"": ""Event"",
        ""name"": ""Kabarett Tipps in \u00d6sterreich: Diese K\u00fcnstler sollten Sie nicht verpassen"",
        ""location"": {
        ""@type"": ""Place"",
        ""address"": {
        ""@type"": ""PostalAddress"",
        ""addressCountry"": ""AT"",
        ""addressLocality"": ""Wien - Landstrasse"",
        ""postalCode"": ""1030"",
        ""streetAddress"": null
        },
        ""name"": ""Ganz \u00d6sterreich"",
        ""url"": ""\/l\/ganz-oesterreich""
        },
        ""url"": ""\/e\/kabarett-tipps-in-oesterreich-diese-kuenstler-sollten-sie-nicht-verpassen#st-241664441"",
        ""startDate"": ""2018-06-18"",
        ""endDate"": ""2019-06-24"",
        ""image"": ""https:\/\/cdn.kurier.at\/img\/100\/210\/772\/kabarett.jpg""
        }";
    IEvent @event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(innerHtml);
}
```

I see `Name` being populated, but `Type` and `Context` remain `null`. Anybody else observing this issue?

Comment: Your properties are all read-only (there is no setter).  The `name` property is getting populated via the `name` parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Quoting json.net docs: "Because a JsonConverter creates a new value, a converter will not work with readonly properties because there is no way to assign the new value to the property. Either change the property to have a public setter or place a JsonPropertyAttribute or DataMemberAttribute on the property." I was aware of the public setter issue, but expected to get around it with the attribute. Nevertheless a point to look into! Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Rogers pointed out, my POCO properties were readonly. Json.net's documentation states:

> Because a JsonConverter creates a new value, a converter will not work
>   with readonly properties because there is no way to assign the new
>   value to the property. Either change the property to have a public
>   setter or place a JsonPropertyAttribute or DataMemberAttribute on the
>   property.

Apparently placing that attribute on the property does not have the desired effect. I placed the attribute on the private readonly fields backing the properties, which finally yielded the desired result.
Thanks Brian for the pointer :)